# Can one use loop variable in filter?

Tags: loops, angularjs

Is some kind of the following concept possible in AngularJS, for both: string and boolean properties?

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:'person.isMale'">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:{isMale:true}">
```

or

```
<li ng-repeat="person in people | filter:{isMale:1}">
```

Depending on your data